# Figuring out what "it" might refer to

Tags: word-meaning

> Russian energy giant Gazprom meanwhile warned the government in Kiev that ***it*** would cut off gas exports if ***it*** did not settle a $1.89bn (£1.13bn) debt. In 2009, Gazprom halted supplies to Ukraine in a move that caused shortages across Europe.

(Source: [BBC News](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-26483818))

What does the first and second "it" refer to in this context? I think the first "it" refers to Gazprom and the second refers to Kiev – am I right?

Comment: In the future, put your question in your question, not it the title of your question. Moreover, it's good practice to (a) put your quotes in a "quote box", by adding a ">" character to the beginning of the line, and (b) provide a link to the article, so that others can read more context, if desired. (Sometimes, it's impossible to figure out the meaning of a sentence unless one can also read the previous sentence or paragraph. Don't make people here go search for the article with a search engine.)

Comment: Thank you so much to edit. Actually the previous paragraph had nothing to do with this. Here ut is : The head of the team, Valeriy Sushkevych, said they would participate, but warned: "If something major happens, Ukraine will leave the Games immediately".Russian energy giant Gazprom meanwhile warned the government in Kiev that it would cut off gas exports if it did not settle a $1.89bn (£1.13bn) debt. In 2009, Gazprom halted supplies to Ukraine in a move that caused shortages across Europe.

Comment: The previous paragraph may not have had any relevance **in this instance**, but it's still a good general practice to include the link. Some might want to refer back to the original just to _verify_ that previous text doesn't change the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You read it correctly. The first "it" refers to Gazprom, and the second "it" refers to the government in Kiev (Ukraine).

According to the news, Ukraine still owes Gazprom $1.89bn (£1.13bn), and unless this debt was settled, Gazprom would cut off the gas exports to Ukraine.